# Removal of K objects such that no two are adjacent

Tags: combinatorics

There are 2 rows joined side-by-side with n objects in each row. What is the number of ways to remove exactly k objects such that no two vacant place, after removal, are adjacent to each other .

for example.
when n=4, k=2 answer is 18
when n=5, k=3 answer is 50.

I'm not able to get a formula to solve it for any value of n,k(k<=2*n).[image of how the two rows are joined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piBcf.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Look at this recursive function. It calculates number of variants for given `n, k` and `last` flag (it shows whether we marked cell in the last column).

If we don't mark cell in the current column, we have three variants for the next one: don't mark again, mark top, mark bottom.

If we mark cell in the current column, we have only two variants for the next one: don't mark again or mark cell in opposite row.

Note that code returns correct result **38** for your second example - there are `C(5,3)=10` combinations for distribution of objects by columns. Single combination with disjoined  columns `10101` gives 8 variants, three combinations with joined columns like `01110` give 3*2=6 variants, and six combinations like `01011` give 6*4=24 variants.

Provided code is not effective (it has exponential complexity), so for practical purposes it should be rewritten using dynamic programming - or memoization (saving results of calls in map with n/k/l key and reusing them when needed) or with table approach (fill n/k/l table cell-by-cell).

I leave this conversion as rather easy exercise for author (because author have not shown any own code)

```
def F(n, k, last):
    if k > n:
        return 0
    if k == 0:
        return 1
    if k == n:
        return 2 - last         # 2 if last==0 else 1

    return F(n - 1, k, 0) + (2 - last) * F(n - 1, k - 1, 1)

print(F(4,2,0))
print(F(5,3,0))

>>18
>>38
```